# Is there any way to help color blind people feel the true color like normal people?

Tags: color-blindness

I am Mild Deutans by taking a color blind test.

Deutans is defined by a result as
"Deutans are people with deuteranomaly, a type of red-green color blindness in which the green cones do not detect enough green and are too sensitive to yellows, oranges, and reds.
As a result, greens, yellows, oranges, reds, and browns may appear similar, especially in low light. It can also be difficult to tell the difference between blues and purples, or pinks and grays."

This maps to me. But can I be cured? Or if not, is it possible for me to have a imagine of my blinded color?

Comment: https://www.forbes.com/sites/sethporges/2015/04/28/can-these-glasses-really-fix-color-blindness-we-put-them-to-the-test/#206dd2965e2b